# Disable scrolling animation using smoothScrollToPosition

Tags: android, listview, scrollview, bundle, expandablelistview

I am using expandable listview and updating the list in every 5 seconds, I want to update the list with new data from the same scrolling position as user left with previous data.

I able to achieve this by using `getLastVisiblePosition & onSaveInstanceState`, but there is something strange I notice,

when user left the 0th group expanded, then I populate the list with new data and onSaveInstanceState does not work only for 0th index while it works fine with other group expanded. However I am doing workaround for 0th group index by using getLastVisiblePosition but when new data get updated it reaches to the positon through scrolling after updating the expandable listview, the scrolling is kind of very annoying it should directlty be on last visible position.

So My question is, why the onSaveInstanceState is not working for expanded 0th group or how to disble the annoying scrolling if I am using getLastVisiblePosition.

Any suggestion would be nice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience, getLastVisiblePosition does not work always and index is sometimes very strange, while for onSaveInstanceState, it only works if you are leaving activity and then coming back. Which is not your case and that is why onSaveInstanceState is not working.

I think the best option for you to use onScroll listener and get the last or first visible index position. check the example below

While to remove this annoying animations you should use `setSelection` instead anything like smootScrolling etc.

```
 private int scrollTo
 list.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            scrollTo = firstVisibleItem;
        }
    });
```

Then after setting adapter for listview you should use

```
list.setSelection(scrollTo);
```

I hope it will help you.